# DataGridView does not recognise ="text" in excel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using this code for reading an xls file into my DataGridView (C# Winform, 2010)

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                    "Data Source=" + FileName + ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";
```

But I found that DataGrid's cell is blank but xls file is having value there:
="600+300"

Atleast DataGridView control should show **600+300** there, or at least show something?

How to fetch such values in my DataGridView???

Answer (score 1):

There are many limitations when importing from Excel spreadsheets, one of which is the TypeGuessRows issue. By default the Jet engine will scan only the first 8 rows to determine the datatype of a column and anything that does not match will simply **not be imported** into the data set.

**Suggestion 1:**

To help lessen this problem you can increase the number of rows Excel will scan by setting a registry property called TypeGuessRows to 0 as in the below example.

**Registry Key:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\ExcelRegistry
```

**Key Name:**
TypeGuessRows

**Default Value: 8**

**New Value: 0**

Depending on your OS and Jet version this key may be in a slightly different location, or you may even have to add it.

For more information:
http://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/excel-data-type-guess-registry-setting/

**Suggestion 2:**

Another potentially issue is the format of your cells in Excel. The format will also affect the values the Jet engine can provide. I suggest that you mark all cells as **Text** before importing to provide consistent behaviour.
Note that this may convert dates to Julian format (a count of days since the Epoch) but they can be parsed back quite easily, and this won't happen if the data was entered as Text format to begin with (only with General and Date formatting)